# How to change log4j jdbc adapter db location at run time

Tags: java, log4j

Following is my jdbc adapter for log4j , how to change dblocation at run time

```
log4j.appender.DB=org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender
log4j.appender.DB.driver=org.sqlite.JDBC
log4j.appender.DB.URL=jdbc:sqlite:{To change}
log4j.appender.DB.user=
log4j.appender.JDBC.commit=true
log4j.appender.DB.threshold=trace
log4j.appender.DB.sql=INSERT INTO sfLog(UserID,UserName,IPAddress,Port,UserAgent,Type,Status,Message,Date) VALUES('%X{UserID}','%X{UserName}','%X{IP}','%X{Port}','%X{Agent}','%X{Type}','%X{Status}','%m','%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss}')
log4j.appender.DB.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a property placeholder and a -D on your JVM command line:

e.g.

```
log4j.appender.DB.URL=${myDbUrl}
```

Then on your JVM command line you'd include something like:

```
-DmyDbUrl=blahblahblah
```

Or you could use System.setProperty, but you'd have to do that before log4j initialises.

Comment: but i could get the location at run time only how to set that.